# Find product of solutions of $x^6=-64$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, factoring

> If the six solutions of $x^6=-64$ are written in the form $a+bi$,where
>   $a$ and $b$ are real, then find the product of those solutions with $a>0$.

The answer in my book is given as $4$ but I don't see why.

Can you give me some hint on that?

Comment: You're not supposed to take the product of _all_ the roots. Only the roots with positive real part.

Comment: Ah,I didn't get that part.Me dumb.Sorry for the waste of time

Comment: It is asking product of roots which have positive real part. You know roots of $x^6=1$ represent a regular unit hexagon in complex plane, so roots of $x^6=-1$ are those rotated by $\pi/2$ clockwise, and you have two complex roots with postive real part which are conjugates of each other. Since each must have modulus $2$, then product is $4$. Drawing diagram may clarify it

Comment: Well I will change the question,so that it has some value.

Comment: Okay now the question is not too localized.Thanks again guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The points create a regular hexagon centered at $0$ (with a vertex at $\pm2i$). Each root has its absolute value equal to $\sqrt[6]{64}=2$. There are two roots with $a>0$:

$$2(\cos(\pi/6)\pm i\sin(\pi/6))$$

and their product is equal to

$$4(\cos(\pi/6)- i\sin(\pi/6))(\cos(\pi/6)+ i\sin(\pi/6))$$
$$=4(\cos(\pi/6)^2+\sin(\pi/6)^2)=4$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer @kamilo9875.It's really neat :)

Comment: @Kamil: Nice answer..........+1

Answer (score 3):

$$x^6=-64\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x^6=64e^{\pi i}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=\left(64e^{(2\pi k+\pi)i}\right)^{\frac{1}{6}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=2e^{\frac{1}{6}(2\pi k+\pi)i}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=\begin{cases}2e^{\frac{1}{6}(2\pi\cdot0+\pi)i}\\
2e^{\frac{1}{6}(2\pi\cdot1+\pi)i}\\
2e^{\frac{1}{6}(2\pi\cdot2+\pi)i}\\
2e^{\frac{1}{6}(2\pi\cdot3+\pi)i}\\
2e^{\frac{1}{6}(2\pi\cdot4+\pi)i}\\
2e^{\frac{1}{6}(2\pi\cdot5+\pi)i}\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=\begin{cases}2e^{\frac{\pi i}{6}}\\
2i\\
2e^{\frac{5\pi i}{6}}\\
2e^{-\frac{5\pi i}{6}}\\
-2i\\
2e^{-\frac{\pi i}{6}}\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=\begin{cases}2e^{\pm\frac{\pi i}{6}}\\
\pm 2i\\
2e^{\pm\frac{5\pi i}{6}}
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=\begin{cases}\sqrt{3}\pm1i\\
\pm 2i\\
-\sqrt{3}\pm1i
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=\begin{cases}\sqrt{3}\pm i\\
\pm 2i\\
-\sqrt{3}\pm i
\end{cases}$$

With $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $k:0-5$

---

So only the first one is the one you need, notice that for $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$

$(a+bi)(a+bi)^*=(a+bi)(a-bi)=a^2+b^2$:

$$\left(\sqrt{3}+i\right)\left(\sqrt{3}-i\right)=\left(\sqrt{3}\right)^2+1^2=3+1=4$$

Comment: Wow,that's really a huge effort.Thank you !I am gratefull (I wish I could accept more than one answer ) +1

Comment: @Mr.Y You're more than welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but here is a solution for students with intermediate knowledge.

To find the solutions, restate the equation.

$z^6+64=0$

This can be rewirtten as $(z^3+8i)(z^3-8i)=0$

$(z+2i)(z^2-2zi-4)(z-2i)(z^2+2zi-4)$

Using the quadratic formula, $z = i±\sqrt{-1+4} = i±\sqrt{3}$ and $z = -i±\sqrt{-1+4} = -i±\sqrt{3}$

These solutions with a positive $a$ can be restated as $\sqrt{3}-i$ and $\sqrt{3}+i$. To find the product of these, multiply them both.

$(\sqrt{3}-i)(\sqrt{3}+i) = 3+1 = 4$

**The product of the solutions with $a>0$ is 4.**